# Applying vue-material theme style

Tags: vue.js, sass, vue-material

I'm trying to apply a vue-material style to an active menu option; The following works well:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import '~vue-material/dist/theme/engine.scss';

.md-list {
  .md-selected,
  .router-link-active{
    .md-list-item-text {
      color: md-get-palette-color(blue, A200)
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

I'm trying to get the following to work however, as it will take the selected theme colors into account, but it does not result in any visible change:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import '~vue-material/dist/theme/engine.scss';

.md-list {
  .md-selected,
  .router-link-active{
    .md-list-item-text {
      @include md-theme-component() {
        color: md-theme(primary);
      }
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

It does not result in any errors, but does not seem to work at all - any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!